# How to stop auto-increment on either MX Title Control or Title Master

Tags: playa, relationships, url-title, mx-title-control, title-master

Both MX Title Control and Title Master add an auto-increment value for each relationship entry for the same name.

Is there any way to prevent that? It causes a problem in my site. Or maybe there's another workaround.

It's a little complicated to explain but I will try to be as to-the-point as possible.

The site is a tool for Schools to request Tutors for their Students.

The Students channel is the Playa relationship between the School and the Tutor.

Schools enter the Students' info.

The admin assigns a Student to the Tutor(s) after the request from the School.

Tutors add their schedule, grades, reports, etc about the student.

The Schools can view the details about the Tutors' activities with the Students.

A Student can have multiple Tutors.

The Title of the Tutor assignment is the Student name which happens via Title Master add-on (MX Title Control has the same ability).

But so the URL Title is unique, and number is added. (I believe EE will do this even without the help of Title Control or Title Master.)

**THE PROBLEM**

When trying to get the details from one of the Tutor's reports, the extra number gets involved and the link doesn't work.

[image: Multi Entry Editor]

**Works** 
http://www.vanhove.net/ati/index.php/view-students/student-curriculum-rpt-details/laura-farrell/968

**Doesn't work**
http://www.vanhove.net/ati/index.php/view-students/student-curriculum-rpt-details/laura-farrell**2370**/980

Here is my code for that link

```
<a href="{url_title_path='view-students/student-curriculum-rpt-details'}/{row_id}">{appointment_curriculum_rpt format="%D, %F %d, %Y"}</a>
```

This is a password protected site as it has a lot of confidential info, but I can share these screen grabs.

This image shows the link that works

[image: OK]

This image shows the link that doesn't work

[image: Not OK]

I realize this is a lot of info, hopefully it makes sense. Any fix would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Btw, the title of the entry would normally be the Tutor's name, but that would make it really awkward on the back end. The same Tutor handles multiple students, making it difficult to find a specific entry. So I am using Title Master to make the entry the Student's name.

[image: Entry titles modified by Title Master]

Comment: The increment value is added so each url title is unique. Not unique url titles will cause problems if you use it in urls.

What kind of problem do you have? I think it is better practice to solve that problem.

Comment: Steve, I can't get anything for either of those links, could you update the post with a working link example? And if the issue is that you just to output a URL and somehow remove the added row id ("laura-farrell2370/908" becomes "laura-farrell/908") there are some dirty PHP regex ways to fix this. It wouldn't be pretty but you could mangle the outputted url. I can give you an answer probably if that is an ok solution.

Comment: Go go jchrono! hang on wait, dirty PHP hacks, but thats __my__ game!!! lolz

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It is not clear to me why one student exists multiple times in your database. Normally I would say a student is unique and therefore should exist only once.

If that would be the case you could use the students url_title from the channel tag to generate the links.